# How to handle http.FormFile equivalent in grpc

Tags: grpc, proto, grpc-go

I am very new to grpc and I am refactoring some http handlers to grpc. In there I have found a handler which is relevant to upload a file. In the request, it is sending a file as `http.FormFile` using http multipart form data.

What I found is, there is a way using request chunk data stream to upload file. But what i need is avoid streaming and do it in stateless manner.

I have searched a way to solve this, but I couldn't find a way to do that. Highly appreciate if someone give me a propper solution to do this

Answer (score 3):

### Tl;dr

gRPC was not designed to handle large file uploads in the same way that you would using http multipart form data uploads. gRPC has a (slightly) arbitrary [4MB message limit](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1676#issuecomment-229809402) (also see [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/746)). In my experience, the proper solution is to not use gRPC for large file uploads. That being said, there may be a few options you can try.

### Changing gRPC Call Options

You can manually override the default 4MB message limit using connection options when you dial the gRPC server. For example, see [this](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/issues/2419#issuecomment-435036611):

```
client, err := grpc.Dial("...", 
    grpc.WithDefaultCallOptions(grpc.MaxCallRecvMsgSize(4096)))
```

### Using gRPC Streams

I have needed to use gRPC for file uploads without changing the default message limit options by implementing [my own chunking package](https://github.com/clarkmcc/chunker) to handle it for me over a unary gRPC stream. You mentioned you wanted to avoid using a stream, however I'm providing this as a resource for those who want to avoid changing their gRPC message limit. Using the library, you'll need to wrap your gRPC client. Once a wrapper is created, you can upload anything that is compatible with the `io.Reader` interface.

```
err := chunk.UploadFrom(reader, WrapUploadFileClient(client))
```